# How to style react material-ui LeftNav hover menuItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to style the LeftNav (http://material-ui.com/#/components/left-nav) menuItem hoverColor.

I tried this but to no avail:

```
    <LeftNav
      ref="leftNav"
      docked={false}
      selectedIndex={this.getSelectedIndex()}
      onChange={this.handleLeftMenuChange}
      menuItems={menuItems}
      menuItemStyle={{hoverColor:"#fff"}} />
```

This seems to be the code I'm trying to override: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/menu/menu-item.jsx#L138 -- however, I'm trying to override it through the LeftNav component.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?